# SlickGrid DataView syncGridSelection does not remove the old selection when the table changes

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have a SlickGrid running with a dataView and I'm using the `rowSelectionModel` with the option `multiSelect=false`. When I select something in the grid and then expand my grid by clicking a button to show some hidden rows, the selection is moving correctly, but the old selection still remains on the old row.

This is what I have so far:

```
var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView({inlineFilters: false});
var grid = new Slick.Grid(gridDiv, dataView, columns, options);
grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel({selectActiveRow: true}));
grid.setSelectedRows([]); //make sure the selection is empty
dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    grid.invalidate();
});
dataView.beginUpdate();
dataView.setItems(data);
dataView.setFilter(displayFilter);
dataView.endUpdate();
dataView.syncGridSelection(grid);
grid.render();
```

Here are some screenshots on the behavior:

Before expanding:

[image: screenshot of table before expanding]

Expected behavior after expanding:

[image: screenshot of expected behavior after expanding]

Actual behavior after expanding:

[image: screenshot of actual behavior after expanding]

I'm pretty sure I'm close, but i can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to help me with this :)

EDIT: I might have found something. I'm using `syncGridSelection` which sets some events, but overwrite them later. The events I overwrite are
`dataView.onRowCountChanged()
dataView.onRowsChanged()
grid.onSelectedRowsChanged`

might this be the issue here? I need those events to get the collapse/expand functionality to work. The `grid.onSelectedRowsChanged` is used to pass the selected item to a chart, so it is also required.

EDIT 2:
I was able to reproduce the issue with Example 5, the modified code can be found [in this paste](https://pastebin.com/MzMh6sVc) 
Steps to reproduce:
1. Select item 10
2. Collapse item 7

Comment: Sorry for the lack of response from the Slickgrid community, this is not a straightforward one. The main point I should raise is that you should be using https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid rather than the original MLeibman repo, which is basically dead. The new repo has a ton of bug fixes, improvements and works with modern versions of jQuery. Can you confirm you are doing that.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your reply. Yes I am using your repository.

Comment: OK, great. So if you can provide a test based on one of the example files in the repo, you'll need to specify which example file and exactly what changes you've made, then I'll have a live sample for testing and can help.

Comment: I am basically using the collapse example (5) and have the rowSelection model added. The weird behavior appears when im using this function to toggle an element with a button: `function toggleItem(dataView, itemId) {
    var target = dataView.getItemById(itemId);
    target._collapsed = !target._collapsed;
    dataView.updateItem(target.id, target);
}` so to reproduce it, you might use example 5, add a selection instead of the editing and add a button with that function. I'm sorry i missed adding that to the main post.

Comment: I think i found something, I've updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having had a look at the code, I think that is actually *is* working. It's just that your CSS changes have obscured one point.

There are *selected* row(s) and the *active* row. These are different things. You have set the CSS for both (in the CSS area in the page itself) to look the same. So it looks like the selection is still there when in fact it's been removed, but that row is now active.

Just delete the two CSS rules and have a look.

For extra points, use:

```
dataView.syncGridSelection(grid, true);
```

and the grid will preserve the selections as the selection moves in and out of sight on collapse/expand.

Comment: Hi Ben, that was the problem. Thank you so much!